# How do I encourage reopen requests or otherwise bring attention to it?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

[A question that I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498981/how-can-i-fully-close-an-ipad-app) was later closed, but my accepted answer continues to get upvotes. It was closed because it was perceived as not being a developer question but rather one from an end user. Comments on the question and the answer, however, make it clear that it's something that developers need to know yet many don't, and they find the question and answer helpful.

I clicked the "reopen" link, but as I understand it, unless a certain number of others also vote to reopen it, it will stay closed. As a result, the closed nature of the question (likely) means developers who need the information won't follow a link to it.

If I don't really know other SO users who could request that it be reopened, what can I do so it gets more attention, or at least has some hope of getting reopened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can flag the question for moderator attention, and one (or more) of us will make a decision.

As you can tell, mods can close questions instantly — we can also reopen them just as instantly.

<del>But, let me just say right now that *I'm* not very keen on reopening the question, now that it has already been answered and the OP has admitted that the question was asked more from a user's perspective than a developer's (as well as accepting your answer to that effect)...</del>

OK, I've reopened and protected it as mentioned in my comment. Just in time to save it from a painful deletion as well, phew!

Comment: Ah, ok, great. I was under the impression that flags were... bad things, I guess. Thanks.

Comment: ... or maybe I could reopen it but protect it from drive-by non-answers as well. It does have an excess of 50k views, after all.

Comment: Protecting it seems like a good solution, such that devs who need the info won't be deterred from getting it but it won't otherwise spiral into useless directions.